# How can I enable my-huge file on windows server?

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, mysql-5, windows

I installed Windows Server 2008 and MySQL 5.5.
Now I need configure MySQL for huge InnoDB tables and a lot of connections.

I see that on my Windows Server, there is a `my-huge` file(configs files that come with mysql :my, my-huge,my-large .ini) with configuration inside the mysql directory.

How can the my-huge configuration be enabled?

Answer (score 2):

You need to stop mysqld, swap in my-huge.ini, and start up mysqld

```
cd C:\"Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.5"
net stop mysql
rename my.ini my.oldini
copy my-huge.ini my.ini
net start mysql
```

This will only work if you do not have to resize the log files.

If you have to resize ib_logfle0 and ib_logfile1, rename them before startup

```
cd C:\"Program Files\MySQL\MySQL 5.5"
net stop mysql
rename my.ini my.oldini
copy my-huge.ini my.ini
cd data
rename ib_logfile0 ib_logfile0.bak 
rename ib_logfile1 ib_logfile1.bak 
net start mysql
```

Give it a Try !!!